# "We sat, talked and 'spilt'(=drinking?) two pitchers of beer"

Tags: word-usage

> We sat, talked and **spilt** two pitchers of beer.

Does "spill" have the meaning of drinking?

Comment: This seems like a misquote or misspelling. The phrase was probably "*split*" two pitchers, meaning they were shared. In any case, "spilt" wouldn't commonly mean drinking.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns an obvious typographical error.

Comment: It is not necessarily a typographical error, and as Lawrence points out,  *to spill* is possible. (Note Googling for the exact sentence using either *spilt* or *spilt* provides few returns, and several from what appear to be a language learning environment. Best to **not close**,  as the question could come up again.)

Comment: Source, please. Otherwise we are guessing about this being a typo. or something else.

Answer (score 3):

*Spill* normally has a sense that it was accidental/unintentional:

> **Spill** *verb*
>   1 Cause or allow (liquid) to flow over the edge of its container, especially unintentionally
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/spill)

It is possible to use the term [metaleptically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metalepsis), but it would require strong cues from the context.

Here's an example in the sense you mean (emphasis, mine):

> Always lookin to *spill beers* with friends Jim. I bet you have a few good stories of your own.
>   [- admin, Spillin Beer With Brian](http://www.spillinbeerwithbrian.com/guitar-hero/)

Finally, why *spilt* rather than the prosaic *drank*? It's hard to say conclusively without more context, but it might be more evocative of a beer-drinking session. Intoxication can impair motor control.

One can imagine spilling small (or not so small) amounts while pouring from pitcher to glass, as well as afterwards. I'm not sure whether two pitchers of beer is sufficient to induce intoxication to this extent - it might depend on the size of the pitchers, among other things - but pouring any liquid from a large container is prone to spillage in any case, particularly from pitchers that contain ice cubes.

Capturing the ambiance and general setting of the conversation in a single word would be strong justification for using *spilt* instead of *poured*. The non-standard phrase in the context of your sentence also helps to focus the reader's attention on the allusion.